# jQuery bringing back more than 1 row of data from table

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a table, currently with 2 rows. Next to these rows I have an icon, which when clicked, brings up a dialog box, and in this dialog box is a button which when pressed, is to run a function which copies the selected item to another file

So pretend we're in my dialog box, and this is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(function() {
    $("#save").on("click", saveNote);
  });
})
```

This calls the following function:

```
function saveNote() {

    var OpenNote = $('.dlg_lineNote');
    var row = jQuery(OpenNote.closest("tr"));
    var cpyItem = row.find(".IPROD").text();
    $('div#dialogD').data('dataIPROD', cpyItem);

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'B2BUNV400.PGM',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            task: 'copyItem',
            cpyItem: cpyItem
        },
    }).done(function(message) {
        $("#saveComment").html("Saved");

    });

}
```

My table has two rows with the following items:

row1: 97940G96058445V
row2: 32253216058445

Here is the html:

```
<tr class="altcol1">   
<input type="hidden" name="IPRODa" value="97940G96058445V" />

  <td class="" align="center"><span><a class="icon-sitemap split dlg_lineNote" href="#" id="dlg_lineNote" title="Copy item to LXF files" href=""></a></span></td> 
  <td align="center" class="IPROD">97940G96058445V</td>
  <td class="text" align="center">PA</td>
  <td class="text" align="center">F7940</td>
  <td class="text" align="center">G9</td>
  <td class="text" align="center">58</td>
  <td class="text" align="center">44</td>
  <td class="text" align="center">5</td>
  <td class="text num" align="center">6.000</td>
</tr>

<tr class="altcol2">   
<input type="hidden" name="IPRODa" value="32253216058445" />

  <td class="" align="center"><span><a class="icon-sitemap split dlg_lineNote" href="#" id="dlg_lineNote" title="Copy item to LXF files" href=""></a></span></td> 
  <td align="center" class="IPROD">32253216058445</td>
  <td class="text" align="center">PA</td>
  <td class="text" align="center">F2253</td>
  <td class="text" align="center">21</td>
  <td class="text" align="center">58</td>
  <td class="text" align="center">44</td>
  <td class="text" align="center">5</td>
  <td class="text num" align="center">6.000</td>
</tr>
```

This is the html for the dialog:

```
<div id="dialogD">


<button id="save">Copy Item</button>



</div>
```

This is jQuery I have to open said dialog:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('div#dialogD').dialog({ autoOpen: false, height: 250, width: 300 })
    $('.dlg_lineNote').click(function(){

    var OpenNote = $(this); 
    var row = jQuery(OpenNote.closest("tr")); 
    var cpyItem = row.find(".IPROD").text();    

        $('div#dialogD').data('dataIPROD',cpyItem);

            jQuery.ajax(
        {
            url: 'B2BUNV400.PGM', 
            type: 'POST',
            data: {task: 'copyItem', Item: cpyItem},                
        }).done(function(message)
            {
            $("#notetext").val(message);
            $('div#dialogD').dialog('open');    
            }); 

            $(document).ready(function() {
        $(function() {
            $("#save").on("click", saveNote);
});
```

})
            })

And the result:

task=copyItem&cpyItem=97940G96058445V32253216058445

Notice cpyItem is actually retrieving both the item records in the table, instead of the item I have clicked when opening the dialog box

Whichever item I chose to 'save', it is pulling both rows...

I hope this makes sense

Appreciate any help in advance

Note: I do not use jquery very often

Edit: This is my updated code

```
    <script>
        jQuery(function() {
            jQuery("input:submit, input[type=button], input[type=submit], button, 
          .button").button();
        });

         $(document).ready(function() {
         $('div#dialogD').dialog({ autoOpen: false, height: 250, width: 300 })
    $('.dlg_lineNote').click(function(){

        var OpenNote = $(this); 
        var row = jQuery(OpenNote.closest("tr")); 
        var cpyItem = row.find(".IPROD").text();    

            $('div#dialogD').data('dataIPROD',cpyItem);

                jQuery.ajax(
            {
                url: 'B2BUNV400.PGM', 
                type: 'POST',
                data: {task: 'copyItem', Item: cpyItem},                
            }).done(function(message)
                {
                $("#notetext").val(message);
                $('div#dialogD').dialog('open');    
                }); 


})

//  var item = row.find(".IPROD").text();;

            //  $("#save").click({cpyItem: item} ,saveNote);


$('.dlg_lineNote').on('click', function() {
    var row = $(this).closest("tr");
    var cpyItem = row.find(".IPROD").text();
    $('div#dialogD').data('dataIPROD', cpyItem);
});

function saveNote() {
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'B2BUNV400.PGM',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        task: 'copyItem',
        cpyItem: $('div#dialogD').data('dataIPROD') //get the value of the last selected row
    },
  }).done(function(message) {
    $("#saveComment").html("Saved");
  });
}   
    })
    </script>
```

Comment: You should share your HTML markup as well.

Comment: As suggested my good friend Darth, I have included the HTML

Comment: Where's your `tr` in the markup? You're looking for closest `tr` but there isn't any

Comment: Sorry DNK buddy, I was in the middle of editing my original post, should be there now

Comment: No problem! So you're saying that your `var cpyItem` has the value of both rows?

Comment: It looks like `$('.dlg_lineNote');` is selecting more than one element - there is one element in every row which has that class. You need to get the context of the current row somehow - probably grab the current button context using `this` and then traverse the DOM from there to get the current tr using closest (as you do now)

Comment: @ADyson Could you give me an example please? Thanks

Comment: @JamieAllen done...see below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you're selecting the fields from every row with `$('.dlg_lineNote');`.

What you need to do instead is identify the row which was clicked on. You can use a data-attribute on the button to hold the value from the row, as you do now (although in your current code the data attribute is redundant), but you need to change the location where you set the value to the moment when the row is clicked on (rather than the dialog button), so you can easily identify the right row:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('div#dialogD').dialog({ autoOpen: false, height: 250, width: 300 });

  $('.dlg_lineNote').on('click', function() {

    var row = $(this).closest("tr"); //use "this" to get the exact element clicked on. From here we can get to the exact tr, instead of selecting all of them at once.
    var cpyItem = row.find(".IPROD").text();
    $('div#dialogD').data('dataIPROD', cpyItem);
  });

  $("#save").click(saveNote);
});

function saveNote() {
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'B2BUNV400.PGM',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        task: 'copyItem',
        cpyItem: $('div#dialogD').data('dataIPROD'); //get the value of the last selected row
    },
  }).done(function(message) {
    $("#saveComment").html("Saved");
  });
}
```

Comment: Ok I get this, but where do I stick the dialog open code?

 $('div#dialogD').dialog('open')


Ignore this question

Comment: I understand this was probably like pulling teeth, but.....Its working! Thanks for all the help

Comment: I owe you a beer

Answer (score 2):

Your `OpenNote` variable is pointing to two objects as it's selecting by class and there's two `td` elements with that class.

You need to select the closest `td` with the class `.dlg_lineNote` to the item you choose to save.

How do you choose which item to save? I know you click the save button in your dialog but you need a way of relating that to a specific row

You could do it like this:

```
var row;
$('.dlg_lineNote').on('click', function() {
    row = $(this).closest("tr");
});

function saveNote() {
    var cpyItem = row.find(".IPROD").text();
    $('div#dialogD').data('dataIPROD', cpyItem);

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'B2BUNV400.PGM',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            task: 'copyItem',
            cpyItem: cpyItem
        },
    }).done(function(message) {
        $("#saveComment").html("Saved");

    });

}
```

Comment: Sorry Jamie, I undeleted an answer that I posted earlier before you posted your markup! See edits

Comment: I have small icon which when clicked, brings up the dialog box - I have edited my question to include the jQuery for dialog box

Comment: OK that's fine, so you could get the closest `td` with the class `.dlg_lineNote` on the click of your icon, rather than on the click of your save button. This way you will be relating to that specific row

Comment: @JamieAllen do you really need the dialog box? Why not make the button in the tr do the task directly? It would help solve this problem.

Comment: @JamieAllen see my edits, untested but hopefully you get an idea of what I mean

Comment: @ADyson Probably not, but I am using it as a kind of message to the user before they commit to the save. I am aware it should probably be a warning message of some kind, giving the user the option to Save, or cancel

Comment: @DNKROZ I tried this, but the save function isn't executing anymore

Comment: @JamieAllen I've written an answer, but all the same this looks like it ought to work as well. You're sure there are no console errors? Have you debugged to see if the AJAX request gets fired? Or are you saying it never enters the function at all? Step through your code in the debugger to see where it actually goes.

Comment: The function never fires is what I meant

Comment: So you're still calling it on click of the save button but now it doesn't get hit?

Comment: I've added the full code in the original question, as this looks like I am being vague, but in reality its not firing the saveNote function  anymore, I tried to debug in the console but couldn't get that far

Comment: Because you're not calling the `saveNote` function anymore, you still need to do that when you click your save button. My example was just to solve your issue, not the whole code you should be using

Comment: I do appreciate this probably works, but sometimes I need spoon fed as @ADyson has done. Thanks buddy